# How composite index works ? and what is the efficient way to do data manipulation on composite index

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-delete, composite-primary-key

How does composite index work in db2 ?
We have a table with data, similar to what I described below. 
primary key (B,C)

```
  Table "D" has Table B's key and Table C's key
   B|C
  -----
   1|1
   1|2
   1|3
   2|4
   2|5
   3|5
```

Now if I want to delete rows with C column having values in ( 1,2,3 ) will it be efficient if I query like this

```
Delete from D where C in ( 1,2,3)
```

or should I use B column values as well to achieve better performance ?

If I have to explain a little more elaborate, then

- Table A has ONE TO MANY relation with Table B
- Table B has ONE TO MANY relation with Table C

Now we have another table D which holds keys of both Table B and Table C.

Here I am trying to delete rows on the basis of Table C's key. If I required to use Table B's key as well, how should I query it ? I have written select query but I had to use C.* to filter table D values.

```
SELECT C.Bkey, C.Ckey 
    FROM TableC C 
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON C.id = B.id
    INNER JOIN TableA A ON B.other_id = A.other_id
    WHERE A.other_id = 123 AND Ckey in (1,2,3)
```

Do we have anything similar for delete ? Or should I use two "IN" clauses ( one for BKey column values and one for Ckey column  )

```
 DELETE FROM TableD 
    WHERE Bkey IN 
     ( 
        SELECT B.Bkey 
          FROM TableB tB 
          INNER JOIN TableA tA
          ON tB.someId = tA.someId
          WHERE someId = 123
      ) AND 
  Ckey IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: What's wrong with creating an index on `TableD (C, B)`?

Comment: Most of our queries query using B column only. So I believe the database index was designed as (B,C) and if creating new index is solution , I could create index for C column alone which will be efficient ( I am not sure here if column with duplicate values can be used for indexing )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a composite index with columns `(B, C)`, then the ordering makes a difference.  In general, a query *only* restricting `C` will not use the index (or will not use it efficiently).

The best situation is an equality condition on `B` followed by any condition on `C`.

This is true regardless of whether the logic is in a `delete` or `select`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Gordon. In that case do you think the Delete query I wrote is fine ? or should I change something ? I have given columnB condition first assuming that will get better performance.

Comment: @Raja . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, providing sample data *and* the table definitions for the two tables.  I think the index would be used at least partially for the query.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have created new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007262/is-there-any-better-way-to-write-this-quiery If you find time, assist me.  :) Good Day