# Is there any better way to write this query

Tags: sql, db2, sql-delete

I designed below query for my delete operation. I am new to SQL and just wanted to check with experienced people here if it is fine or any better way to do this. I am using DB2 database

```
DELETE FROM TableD
    WHERE B_id IN 
     ( 
        SELECT B.B_id
          FROM TableB tB 
            INNER JOIN TableA tA
              ON tB.A_id = tA.A_id
          WHERE A_id = 123
      ) AND 
  C_id IN (1,2,3)
```

This has two IN clause which I am little worried and not sure if I could use EXISTS clause anywhere.

Database Structure as below:

- Table A has ONE TO MANY relation with Table B
- Table B has ONE TO MANY relation with Table C
- Table B has ONE TO MANY relation with Table D
- Table D has composite primary key ( B_id, C_id )

Table D data somewhat similar to below

```
   B_id|C_id
  ----------
   1   |  1
   1   |  2
   1   |  3
   2   |  4
   2   |  5
   3   |  5
```

Here I have to delete rows which have C_id in array of values. But since the index is a composite of B_id and D_id, I am retrieving related B_id to the particular entity of Table A by equality operator A_id=123

Comment: What do you mean with "better"? Better for the given database design and the data that is stored? If yes, then please add information about it. If you mean the formatting, well, yes, the query looks nice... :)

Comment: Haha :P Sure, I will add more details. 2 mins :)

Comment: I have added more details Data_henrik

Comment: You seem to be trying to design a query around your index -- that's not the right approach. Design your indexes around your queries instead.

Comment: True mustaccio, But its a production database and implementing a change is not that easy :( I have to go with what I have on hand and when things doesn't work , they will come back to me for solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't necessarily anything wrong with your method.  However, a useful alternative technique to know is [merge](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html):

```
merge into TableD
using ( 
    select distinct 
        B.B_id
      from TableB tB 
        inner join TableA tA on
           tB.A_id = tA.A_id and
           A_id = 123
) AB
on 
    TableD.B_id = AB.B_id and
    C_id in (1,2,3)
when matched then delete;
```

Note that I had to use `distinct` on the inner query to prevent duplicate matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge like this too :

```
   merge into TableD
   using TableB tB
   on B.B_id = TableD.B_id
   and tB.A_id in (select A_id from TableA tA where A_id = 123)
   and C_id in (1,2,3)
   when matched then delete;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to down-vote you for copying dan1111 answer :|

Comment: This is a different way to use merge, not a copy of my answer.

Comment: Ahh, okay, my mistake then. Apologies (:

Comment: No problem , this way its a other possiblity to write . without the distinct but with duplicates , merge of dan1111 its better .

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM TableD tD 
WHERE
  EXISTS ( 
    SELECT
      tB.B_id 
    FROM
      TableB tB 
    WHERE
      A_id = 123 
      AND tB.B_id = tD.B_id
  ) 
  AND C_id IN (1, 2, 3)